# useState updates but when i call the state afterwards it is the previous version?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have the following function that refreshes my states

```
const refreshAfterCreate = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MICROSERVICE_COMPANY_URL + '/companies',         {method: 'GET'});
        const data = await res.json();
        await setCompanies(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al realizar el fetch:', error);
      }
      try {
        const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MICROSERVICE_SERVICE_URL + '/services',        {method: 'GET'});
        const data = await res.json();
        await setServices(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al realizar el fetch:', error);
      }
    };
```

After calling the function with await, I console.log(companies) and console.log(services) and is the previous data.

I tried adding these useEffects

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Companies Updated', companies);
}, [companies]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Services Updated', services);
}, [services]);
```

These work since it logs the updated value. When I call the function above and log everything it updates the values first but then goes back to the previous state, this image helps understand.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, setState is not executed immediately, if you want to access data that was recently updated you have two ways

- Using useEffect
- Or if you want immediately access data after setState (1 line below setState) use the same value that you are passing to setCompanies or set setServices

Extra tip: Don't use await setState because setState doesn't return a promise, it is not necessary to do

Comment: The useEffect by some reason wasn't working correctly for me but I changed my code for the second one and it worked! Thanks!